# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 119 record(s) for TopicJAVA-0: 60030 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, timeout, kafka-producer-api

Here is my code and dependency.I am trying to write Messages to KAfka using a Producer API. And The topic is being also created though the messages are not being send to Kafka topic with the following exception

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 119 record(s) for TopicJAVA-0: 60049 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("bootstrap.servers","10.1.7.82:6667");
        map.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        map.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        map.put("metadata.fetch.timeout.ms", "60000");
        map.put("request.timeout.ms", "60000");
        map.put("batch.size",16384);
        map.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(map);
    // Write
        // create the topic message, enter topic name and message
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("TopicJAVA", "msg from java");
        // function to push the message to kafka topic
        RecordMetadata meta=producer.send(record).get();
        System.out.println("Message Sent"+meta.partition());
        Thread.sleep(500);
        producer.close();

}
```

And here is my dependency POM

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.gaurav.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kakfa-producer-consumer-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>kakfa-producer-consumer-example</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Ashok Kafka Dependencies -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

I have absolutely no idea on what are missing here.An insight into this would be really helpful.Our kafka version is 10.1.2.6.4.0-91
M trying to resolve it for the last 3 days but feeling helpless

Comment: usually happens when you have `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` in that partition or you are unable to connect to the broker.

Comment: @Paizo Thank you for replying but how do I solve the issue currently.M new to kafka and quite hazy on this cluster things

Comment: Check the kafka logs and make sure it is up and running with a leader per topic, make sure your advertised host in the broker configuration match `"bootstrap.servers","10.1.7.82:6667"`

Comment: @Paizo the configuration matches for the bootstrap.servers.When i am creating the topics and sending messages form the kafka-producer console with commands i can retrieve the messages with the console commands.But somehow its not working for the java program.I tried callback mechanisms though it is showing the same exception in detailed above in my problem statement.

Comment: @Paizo. Thank you for responding.However,The issue is resolved.The issue was with my VM etc.hosts. my kafka was running on a hadoop cluster which my VM couldnt ping through the system firewall.I just had to add the cluster node into the host lists in my VM and hola it worked fine.I can retrieve and consume the messages.

Comment: you are welcome, thank you for sharing the root cause

Comment: @Rajiv please mark the question as closed by writing a short answer to the question and then clicking the tick mark